# Android SQLite max size for one application

Tags: android, sqlite

I have two questions regarding to Android SQLite database. I tried to find it in the Internet but I did not succeed.

1) What is a maximum size of data that can be stored in SQLite database for one application?

2) How does the phone behaves if the maksimum size is exceeded and the application would try to save more data in the database?

I think that answers will depend more on your experience than on the documentation. Looking forward to seeing your answers. Best regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the maximum values are listed in the documentation.

http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html

If you attempt to exceed the maximum file size, an exception will be thrown.